# Convert POJO to Map that works with GWT

Tags: java, gwt

The idea is to have a POJO like:

```
class MyBean {
  long id;
  int count;
  public void setCount(int count){
   this.count = count;
  }
}
```

Now, I need that the count be stored automatically as:

```
put("count", count);
```

or simply put, `put("fieldname", fieldvalue);`

Is there a library that can be used for this purpose that `MyBean` can exetnd to? I can easily do a copy constructor or something, however, the point here is automation and besides there are so many models in my app that will be having this Map stored POJO values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a simple PropertyMapGenerator using [Apache Commons BeanUtils' PropertyUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils//api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html)

```
public class PropertyMapGenerator {
    public static Map<String, Object> getPropertyMap(Object object) {
    HashMap<String, Object> propertyMap = new HashMap<>();

    // retrieve descriptors for all properties
    PropertyDescriptor[] descriptors = PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(object);

    for (PropertyDescriptor descriptor : descriptors) {
        // check if there is a reader method for this property i.e. if it can be accessed
        if (descriptor.getReadMethod() != null) {
            String name = descriptor.getName();
            try {
                propertyMap.put(name, PropertyUtils.getProperty(object, name));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // handle this properly
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return propertyMap;
    }
}
```

Now you can simply pass your POJOs to this generator:

```
Map<String, Object> propertyMap = PropertyMapGenerator.getPropertyMap(myBean);
```